# Absolute value of a complex number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it valid :$$ abs(a+ib)/abs(c+id)=abs[(a+ib)/(c+id)]$$ ? and also $$abs(a+ib)^m*abs(c+id)^n=abs[(a+ib)^m*(c+id)^n]$$ when i stands for imaginary number. I were trying to multiply by complex conjugate

Comment: Do we know that one of $c,d$ is non-zero?

Comment: yes. c, d non-zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proposition 1**

for any $Z_{1},Z_{2}$ are complex numbers,then we have
$$|Z_{1}Z_{2}|=|Z_{1}||Z_{2}|$$
proof:
$$|Z_{1}Z_{2}|^2=(Z_{1}Z_{2})(\overline{Z_{1}Z_{2}})=(Z_{1}\overline{Z_{1}})(Z_{2}\overline{Z_{2}})=|Z_{1}|^2|Z_{2}|^2$$
so
$$|Z_{1}Z_{2}|=|Z_{1}||Z_{2}|$$
**Proposition 2**
$$\left|\dfrac{Z_{1}}{Z_{2}}\right|=\dfrac{|Z_{1}|}{|Z_{2}|},Z_{2}\neq 0$$

proof: since
$$\left|\dfrac{Z_{1}}{Z_{2}}\right|=\left|Z_{1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{Z_{2}}\right|=|Z_{1}\cdot Z^{-1}_{2}|=|Z_{1}|\cdot|Z_{2}|^{-1}=\dfrac{|Z_{1}|}{|Z_{2}|}$$
**Remarks.**
$$|Z_{1}Z_{2}|=|Z_{1}||Z_{2}|,\Longrightarrow |Z^n|=|Z|^n$$
so
$$|Z^m_{1}|\cdot|Z^n_{2}|=|Z^m_{1}\cdot Z^n_{2}|$$

Comment: is z a complex number?

Comment: yes.it is clear

Comment: Is $abs(z_1)^n*abs(z_2)^m=abs((z_1)^n*(z_2)^m)$?

Comment: @user188750,Yes,